# Associating three models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

After reading up on [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in the Rails Guide, it's not clear to me how I can associate three models, or if that would be unwise.  I want to use the same comments model for both comments on a blog and on another page.  Would it make sense to have two comments models in this case?  What kind of associations would I use to connect the models if I decided to have only one comments model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you missed block with polymorphic models

Check it out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

You can attach comment to multiple models, with help of them